# Generic type with array of properties of another type

Tags: typescript

Sorry if the title is confusing, I really don't know how to put it in words.

Say I have any type, such as this one:

```js
type Car = {
  color: string;
  speed: number;
}
```

Using some Typescript generic type, I want to transform the type Car into this:

```js
type TransformedCar = {
  color: string | string[]
  speed: number | number[]
}
```

The idea is to have some

```js
type Transformed<T> = ???

type TransformedCar = Transformed<Car>
```

Comment: `type Transformed<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] | T[K][]; }`

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!